# Hosting Dynamic Content on GitHub?

Tags: web-hosting, dynamic, server-side-scripting, github

Is it possible to host dynamic content through GitHub:Pages?  More specifically, we are using GitHub Enterprise, so we have a little more control, but I'm not aware of what dynamic content languages (Ruby, Python, ???) we might be able to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it based on rendering plain files from a git repository, I don't think you can use dynamic information. The goals of Github Pages is to show a static site easily from an open source project.

You can still [contact them](https://help.github.com/contact?article_slug=what-are-github-pages) and I think you have a dedicated support if you use Github Enterprise.

Comment: The project doesn't have to be open source if you have a paid Github account. But otherwise you're right. Github isn't really a general web hosting provider. They aren't set up for that, so I wouldn't expect to be able to run custom sever-side code on their servers.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté well in first place, Github Pages were set to have a kind of *built-in* website to present a repository (with a branch called `gh-pages`), nope? In fact, after it was used to build a static website without a proper open source project attached :)